# Delete content in a XML file before parsing

Tags: iphone, xml, sdk

I am parsing a XML file using NSXMLParser. And there is a certain section that is completely f*#@ed up and ends up breaking the parsing process. Basically its a bit of HTML that they never wrapped in CDATA.

Is there anyway I can delete this before sending it through the parser so it doesn't break. (The information in this bit is not important and can be thrown away)

The XML kind of looks like this

```
<foo>
    text</span></li><li> 
    <span class="ft">Not important:</span> 
    <span class="fc"><a href="Some random link">0</a>  
</foo>
```

As you can see the span tags are all messed up. How can  just get rid of foo's content completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run [HTML tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) on the data first - this will give valid XML. You can add non html tags into the configuration file

Comment: I just want the section gone. I don't want to try to fix it.

Comment: The trouble is that to remove foo - the usual way is using a regex but using regexes on xml does not work well - so I think fixing the xml and then removing foo is the easiest way - unless there is only one foo element and you always want to remove it